# CSS animation in Firefox not work

Tags: html, css

Hello i create animation for my box and all work in chrome. But in firefox dont work.
I try to use -moz- but again nothing.

**CSS code for animation what i using is :**

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}

div.pulse { opacity: 0.75; }
div.pulse:hover {
  -moz-animation-name: pulse; 
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1; 

  -webkit-animation-name: pulse; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
}
```

Anyone can tell what i do wrong? Whay dont work in mozila?

Comment: Onlu work in chrome :/

Comment: the FF version of `-webkit-transform` is the `-moz-transform` property.

Answer (score 7):

You need to define the FF version of the animation and transform **as well as** the webkit version

```
@-moz-keyframes pulse { /* older versions of FF */
  from {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to { 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to { 
    transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this work my big mistake i try to use safri for -moz- deam :/

Comment: firefox has native support of transform, no need for vendor specifics

Answer (score 4):

Let me get this all straightened out for you.

[**Transformations:**](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

There are 2 vendor specifics for the transform and they are "-webkit-" and "-ms-". -webkit- being for safari and chrome, and -ms-transform is only for IE9 suppport.

[**Animation Keyframes:**](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation)

There is only 1 vendor specific for animation keyframes and that is -webkit-, which is for safari and chrome (no IE9 support at all).

Therefore you only need to worry about the -webkit- vendor specific for your situation, but you still have to do the non vendor specific one as well, especially since you want it to show up in firefox.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b93Nz/1/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);        
        opacity: 0.75;
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);       
        opacity: 1.0;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);       
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
}



@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);    
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);    
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% { 
    transform: scale(1.0);    
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}

div.pulse { opacity: 0.75; }
div.pulse:hover {
  animation-name: pulse; 
  animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
}

.pulse{
  background:red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each vendor has it's own implementation. `Webkit` refers to the layout engine that Apple's Safari browser and Google Chrome are powered by. Internet Explorer also has it's own vendor implementation. Here are all of the variations:

```
.transformed {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
    transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: no need for -moz- or -ms- transform, -ms- is only for IE9 support for transform

Answer (score 0):

you are missing @-moz-keyframe

working example:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwEiD

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
        opacity: 0.75;
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}

div.pulse { opacity: 0.75; }
div.pulse:hover {
  -moz-animation-name: pulse; 
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1; 

  -webkit-animation-name: pulse; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
}

.pulse{
  background:red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;

}
```

Comment: no need for -moz-animation, only webkit vendor specific and the base animation are needed.