# Transform scale working on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, css-animations

Once I start animating, on Chrome I get a ripple effect. My circle transform scales up. On Firefox, that exact same animation is ignored for some reason.

```js
$("#animate").click(function() {
  $("#square").toggleClass("animate");
  $("#fab").toggleClass("ripple");
});
```

```css
@keyframes ripple {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(20)
  }
}
#square {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background 0.1s linear 0.6s, transform 1s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#fab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4FB5AB;
  top: 122px;
  right: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.ripple {
  animation: ripple 1s 0.5s;
  transform: scale(20) !important;
  /*Duration - delay */
  transition: transform 0s 1s !important;
}
.animate {
  transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square">
  <div id="fab"></div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="animate">animate</button>
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/Appie/pen/GoQmNO)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @AMACB Have you tried out the animation on both firefox & Chrome?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the animate button. Hmm, that's weird.

Comment: @AMACB Have you noticed the problem now?

Comment: Yes, that is very weird.

Comment: I think that you need to define a `@-moz-keyframe`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143893/css-animation-in-firefox-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start explaining the problem with your code, here is a word of caution - Do not use transitions and animations together. They generally end up causing problems like the one faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142484/combination-of-animation-and-transition-not-working-properly/32142949#32142949).

When an animation is specified on an element, it will take complete control over the properties that are being animated unless there is a rule with `!important` setting. If `!important` setting is used then that rule takes precedence over the animation. (but unfortunately Chrome and Firefox seem to be handling this case differently).

As per [**W3C Spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/):

> CSS Animations affect computed property values. During the execution of an animation, the computed value for a property is controlled by the animation. This overrides the value specified in the normal styling system. ***Animations override all normal rules, but are overriden by !important rules.***

<sup>emphasis is mine</sup>

---

In your code, there were two problems and they are as follows:

- Within `.ripple` selector, you were specifying the `transition-duration` as `0s`, which means, there is no transition at all and that the change of transform is an instant one. As explained in the W3C Spec, Firefox seems to be (correctly) giving the control to the rule with `!important` setting (that is, the `transform` and `transition` within `.ripple` selector) and so it transitions the state change immediately after the specified `1s` delay<sup>**+**</sup>. Chrome lets animation take control and thus produces the effect you are looking for.
- Firefox seems to animate the element quicker than Chrome does and so while a duration of 1s is enough for the animation in Chrome, FF needs it to be 2s to be slower and show the effect.

<sup>**+**</sup> - You can further verify this by removing the `!important` settings on the rules. Once `!important` is removed, the animation would take control.

```js
$("#animate").click(function() {
  $("#square").toggleClass("animate");
  $("#fab").toggleClass("ripple");
});
```

```css
@keyframes ripple {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(20)
  }
}
#square {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background 0.1s linear 0.6s, transform 1s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#fab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4FB5AB;
  top: 122px;
  right: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
#fab.ripple {
  animation: ripple 2s 1s;
  transform: scale(20);
  /*Duration - delay */
  transition: transform 1s 1s;
}
#square.animate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square">
  <div id="fab"></div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="animate">animate</button>
```

Finally, **please do not use `!important` unless it is mandatory**. Instead just make the selector more specific. In the snippet, I have made it more specific by using the `#id.class` format.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not only did you fix my problem but you only gave me a very detailed explanation on what was causing it. I also didn't know I could override css rules by making the selectors more specific, but now I do!

Comment: @5parc: You're welcome buddy. Glad to know that you found it useful :) Yes, the `!important` were the problematic ones (and Firefox is the browser which looks to have implemented it as per specs).

Comment: Sorry just making sure we are on the same page. But the "!important" lines were the ones causing the issue right?

Comment: @5parc: Yes, they were.