# css animation-name property does not allow transform property

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have the library animate.css loaded on my website and I animate an arrow moving onto the page using "fadeInLeftBig"

My html:

```
<div class="swipe-button b-left animated fadeInLeftBig"></div>
```

My css:

```
.swipe-button.b-left {
    left: 10px;
    background-image: url(/images/left-arrow.png);
}

.swipe-button:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
}
```

Animate.css

```
.fadeInLeftBig {
    animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
}

.animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes fadeInLeftBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }

 100% {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translateX(0);
 }
}
```

The `transform: rotate(90deg)` does not work on hover as long as `animation-name: fadeInLeftBig` is set on the element. But works if you unceck or comment it out.

I can see now there are two `transform` properties on the element, but Why does setting the `animation-name` property override the transform property with an `!important` flag from taking effect?

Comment: An animation always overrides the *static* properties. selector specifity (including !important) doesn't play a role here.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984456/transform-scale-working-on-chrome-but-not-on-firefox/34985268#34985268.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vals stated earlier..an animation overrides the static properties.  For what you're trying to achieve, you're best bet is to wrap your swipe-button class with a new fadeInLeftBig div:

```
<div class="fadeInLeftBig animated">
<div class="swipe-button b-left animated"></div>
</div>
```

Then use keyframe animations on both divs.  This separates your animations so that your "fade in" doesn't start over once you unhover your swipe-button. Here's a working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/kj4v36ye/2/  Let me know if you're trying to achieve something else and I can easily modify it.

Answer (score 0):

First at you code your don't close '}' in .fadeInLeftBig.

look at this fiddle:

```
<div class="swipe-button b-left animated fadeInLeftBig"></div>
```

and css

```
.swipe-button.b-left {
    left: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
     width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.swipe-button:hover {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.fadeInLeftBig {
    animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
}
.animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kj4v36ye/

Comment: Yup, but i can't comments when my reputation is low :( I edit my answer :)