# Trouble using animation on border on firefox (at least)

Tags: css, animation, firefox, border

I'm currently having trouble using animation on a border, from none to 50px, in Firefox. Chrome is very okay, but Firefox isn't, and I suppose the same issue will be in Opera.

Here's a little fiddle to show you the problem (try Chrome, then FF): https://jsfiddle.net/Bonlo/kL5g0qdx/

```css
@keyframes fadeBorder {
    from { border: 0 solid rgba(0,0,0,0);}
    to { border: 30px solid black;}
}
.main-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: white;
  animation-name: fadeBorder;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

I suppose that the problem come from the border: none; value, but I don't know how to achieve this...

Edit:

## Resolved!

The thing is that Firefox need an initial definition of border, which is at least :

```
border: 0 solid;
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bonlo/jjwL5e49/)

Comment: Have you seen this post? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143893/css-animation-in-firefox-not-work

Comment: I tried that @Calaris It is not working with prefixes too.

Comment: @Bonlo there might be issue with animating borders in firefox. I checked examples in w3schools in firefox. They are not working properly.

Comment: @Calaris No I didn't, but now it's done;
I had try and finally found the trick !

FF seems to need an initial border definition, and minimum seems to be 0 solid. Working on Firefox 56.0.1. If anyone can tell it's working on Opéra too, it will be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is some issue with animating borders in Firefox, but it could be solved like this:

```css
@keyframes fadeBorder {
    from { border-width: 0; }
    to { border-width: 30px; }
}
.main-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0 solid black; /* <-- added line */
  animation-name: fadeBorder;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Also, don't forget to include animation with different prefixes to support older browsers:

```css
@keyframes fadeBorder { ... }
@-webkit-keyframes fadeBorder { ... }
@-moz-keyframes fadeBorder { ... }
@-o-keyframes fadeBorder { ... }
...
animation-name: fadeBorder;
-webkit-animation-name: fadeBorder;
-moz-animation-name: fadeBorder;
-o-webkit-animation-name: fadeBorder;
...
```

Comment: Yes that's it !