# CSS animation not working correctly on Firefox

Tags: css, animation, svg

I try to make a simple animation. Some objects are turning around 360 degree. Everyting is working correctly when I open it Chrome or mobile browsers. But it not works on Firefox correctly. It has to be turn around on object by origin center just like Google Chrome. I wrote -moz- and -web-kit prefixes, it wasn't help me.

**UPDATE**

If you are just open it up on Firefox and don't do anything you can see work like Google Chrome. But when you're cursor comes in on screen the animation is break. You can see clearly below.

[image]

You can see a little snippet below.

```css
#techs {
  animation: rotate 10s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

#techs>* {
  animation: inherit;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  transform-origin: inherit;
  transform-box: inherit;
}

#certel:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#certel:hover #right-eye {
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

#certel:hover #eyes-open {
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

#moving-objects {
  animation: scale 5s infinite ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#certel {
  animation: action 2s infinite alternate;
}

#eyes-open {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

#right-eye {
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}

@keyframes action {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
}

@keyframes eyes-in {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes eyes-out {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
}

@keyframes baboli {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-1rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg">
  <div class="svg-cmd">
    <div class="svg-cmd-header ">
      <div class="svg-cmd-header-icons"></div>
      <div class="svg-cmd-header-icons"></div>
      <div class="svg-cmd-header-icons"></div>
      <div class="svg-cmd-header-text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 40 500 500">
    <g id="group-objects">
      <circle id="circle" cx="252.469" cy="247.273" r="181.496" fill="#FFF5EC"></circle>
      <g id="moving-objects">
   
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="relative-circle">
      <g id="techs">
        <path id="react_1_" fill="#61DAFB" d="M123.159 130.028a29.303 29.303 0 00-1.457-.459c.081-.33.156-.662.225-.994 1.103-5.356.382-9.671-2.082-11.091-2.362-1.362-6.226.058-10.127 3.454-.384.335-.76.68-1.127 1.034a29.007 29.007 0 00-.75-.693c-4.089-3.631-8.188-5.16-10.649-3.736-2.36 1.366-3.058 5.422-2.065 10.499.099.502.21 1.002.335 1.5-.58.165-1.14.34-1.676.527-4.794 1.671-7.856 4.291-7.856 7.008 0 2.806 3.287 5.621 8.28 7.327.405.138.813.265 1.224.383a28.753 28.753 0 00-.355 1.617c-.947 4.988-.208 8.948 2.146 10.306 2.431 1.401 6.511-.04 10.484-3.512.314-.274.629-.565.945-.871.397.383.806.756 1.224 1.117 3.848 3.312 7.649 4.649 10 3.288 2.429-1.406 3.218-5.661 2.193-10.837a24.297 24.297 0 00-.272-1.21c.287-.084.567-.172.842-.263 5.19-1.72 8.568-4.5 8.568-7.344 0-2.729-3.16-5.366-8.05-7.05zm-12.171-7.632c3.343-2.909 6.467-4.058 7.891-3.237 1.516.875 2.106 4.401 1.153 9.026-.063.301-.13.601-.204.9a46.408 46.408 0 00-6.054-.957 45.522 45.522 0 00-3.828-4.777c.34-.326.687-.644 1.042-.955zm-11.689 17.001a56.582 56.582 0 002.705 4.668 41.185 41.185 0 01-4.173-.671c.4-1.291.893-2.632 1.468-3.997zm-.002-4.549a42.54 42.54 0 01-1.438-3.918 43.912 43.912 0 014.104-.705 56.787 56.787 0 00-2.666 4.623zm1.028 2.275a55.32 55.32 0 014.121-7.146 54.699 54.699 0 018.253.001 58.01 58.01 0 012.182 3.483c.69 1.189 1.341 2.4 1.952 3.633a58.607 58.607 0 01-1.945 3.665 64.198 64.198 0 01-2.172 3.505 58.267 58.267 0 01-4.146.146c-1.409 0-2.779-.044-4.1-.129a54.6 54.6 0 01-4.145-7.158zm16.239 4.604c.456-.79.894-1.59 1.313-2.399.576 1.3 1.083 2.63 1.521 3.983a41.346 41.346 0 01-4.224.72c.478-.759.942-1.527 1.39-2.304zm1.295-6.878a68.322 68.322 0 00-1.302-2.356 62.078 62.078 0 00-1.377-2.265c1.445.183 2.829.425 4.128.722a41.261 41.261 0 01-1.449 3.899zm-9.268-10.115a41.593 41.593 0 012.665 3.217 57.205 57.205 0 00-5.352-.001 43.293 43.293 0 012.687-3.216zm-10.43-5.517c1.515-.877 4.865.373 8.396 3.508.226.201.452.41.679.627a46.244 46.244 0 00-3.857 4.773 47.397 47.397 0 00-6.042.939 29.905 29.905 0 01-.312-1.395c-.852-4.348-.286-7.629 1.136-8.452zm-2.208 23.706a25.354 25.354 0 01-1.117-.35 16.406 16.406 0 01-5.281-2.806 3.996 3.996 0 01-1.69-2.692c0-1.648 2.458-3.751 6.558-5.181a28.16 28.16 0 011.559-.49 46.439 46.439 0 002.207 5.719 46.88 46.88 0 00-2.236 5.8zm10.483 8.817a16.375 16.375 0 01-5.069 3.173 3.997 3.997 0 01-3.176.119c-1.428-.824-2.022-4.003-1.212-8.269.096-.504.207-1.005.331-1.503 2.012.432 4.05.727 6.102.883a47.016 47.016 0 003.887 4.803c-.282.271-.57.536-.863.794zm2.209-2.186a43.524 43.524 0 01-2.725-3.261c.867.034 1.75.051 2.649.051.922 0 1.834-.02 2.733-.061a40.652 40.652 0 01-2.657 3.271zm11.746 2.691a3.996 3.996 0 01-1.482 2.811c-1.427.826-4.479-.248-7.77-3.079-.377-.325-.757-.67-1.139-1.038a45.548 45.548 0 003.795-4.819 45.192 45.192 0 006.132-.945c.092.373.174.738.245 1.095a16.34 16.34 0 01.219 5.975zm1.643-9.661c-.248.082-.502.161-.761.238a45.326 45.326 0 00-2.293-5.736 45.482 45.482 0 002.204-5.652c.463.134.913.275 1.346.425 4.191 1.442 6.746 3.575 6.746 5.218-.001 1.749-2.761 4.022-7.242 5.507z"></path>
        <path id="sass_1_" fill="#CD6799" d="M187.189 410.391a8.872 8.872 0 00-3.881.899c-.399-.79-.798-1.495-.869-2.011-.078-.603-.172-.971-.078-1.689.094-.721.517-1.746.509-1.824-.008-.078-.094-.445-.955-.453-.861-.009-1.604.164-1.69.391a9.367 9.367 0 00-.36 1.275c-.149.783-1.722 3.576-2.622 5.039-.29-.57-.54-1.072-.595-1.471-.079-.604-.172-.971-.079-1.69.094-.72.517-1.745.509-1.823s-.094-.445-.955-.453-1.604.164-1.69.391-.18.76-.36 1.275c-.18.517-2.27 5.181-2.817 6.386a37.08 37.08 0 01-.697 1.448s-.008.023-.032.063c-.148.289-.234.445-.234.445v.008c-.117.211-.242.407-.305.407-.047 0-.133-.563.016-1.331.313-1.619 1.057-4.139 1.049-4.225 0-.047.141-.485-.485-.713-.61-.227-.829.148-.884.148-.054 0-.093.134-.093.134s.68-2.833-1.299-2.833c-1.236 0-2.942 1.354-3.788 2.574-.532.29-1.667.908-2.88 1.573-.461.259-.939.517-1.385.759-.032-.031-.063-.07-.094-.102-2.395-2.559-6.823-4.366-6.636-7.802.071-1.252.5-4.538 8.506-8.53 6.589-3.246 11.832-2.348 12.739-.352 1.299 2.848-2.809 8.139-9.617 8.906-2.598.289-3.959-.713-4.304-1.089-.359-.392-.415-.415-.548-.337-.219.118-.078.471 0 .674.204.531 1.041 1.471 2.457 1.933 1.252.407 4.296.634 7.982-.79 4.124-1.597 7.348-6.033 6.401-9.751-.947-3.771-7.207-5.016-13.131-2.911-3.521 1.253-7.34 3.225-10.087 5.791-3.263 3.052-3.779 5.705-3.568 6.816.759 3.943 6.197 6.51 8.373 8.412-.11.063-.211.117-.298.164-1.087.54-5.235 2.707-6.268 5-1.174 2.599.188 4.461 1.087 4.711 2.794.775 5.666-.617 7.208-2.919 1.541-2.3 1.354-5.29.642-6.659a.181.181 0 00-.031-.047c.281-.164.571-.336.853-.5a41.378 41.378 0 011.572-.885c-.266.728-.462 1.596-.556 2.848-.117 1.472.485 3.381 1.276 4.133.352.328.767.336 1.033.336.923 0 1.338-.768 1.8-1.674.563-1.111 1.072-2.403 1.072-2.403s-.634 3.49 1.088 3.49c.626 0 1.26-.813 1.541-1.229v.008s.016-.023.047-.078l.102-.164v-.016a68.34 68.34 0 001.651-3.083c1.08-2.129 2.121-4.789 2.121-4.789s.093.648.414 1.729c.188.635.579 1.33.892 2.004-.25.352-.407.547-.407.547l.008.009c-.204.265-.423.556-.666.837-.853 1.018-1.87 2.184-2.01 2.52-.165.399-.125.688.187.924.228.172.634.195 1.049.172.767-.055 1.307-.242 1.573-.359.415-.148.9-.376 1.354-.713.837-.618 1.346-1.502 1.299-2.668-.023-.643-.234-1.283-.493-1.887.078-.109.148-.219.227-.328 1.323-1.933 2.348-4.054 2.348-4.054s.094.649.415 1.729c.157.548.478 1.143.759 1.722-1.244 1.009-2.011 2.183-2.285 2.95-.492 1.424-.109 2.066.619 2.215.329.07.798-.086 1.142-.234a5.27 5.27 0 001.448-.744c.837-.617 1.643-1.479 1.596-2.645-.023-.533-.164-1.057-.36-1.564 1.056-.439 2.417-.682 4.155-.479 3.725.438 4.461 2.763 4.319 3.74-.14.979-.923 1.511-1.181 1.676-.258.164-.344.219-.321.336.031.172.157.164.375.133.305-.055 1.956-.79 2.027-2.59.119-2.301-2.072-4.813-5.946-4.789zm-28.735 9.687c-1.236 1.346-2.958 1.854-3.701 1.424-.798-.461-.485-2.449 1.033-3.873.924-.869 2.113-1.674 2.903-2.168.18-.109.446-.266.767-.461.055-.032.087-.047.087-.047l.187-.118c.555 2.034.023 3.827-1.276 5.243zm8.999-6.119c-.43 1.049-1.33 3.732-1.877 3.584-.47-.125-.759-2.16-.094-4.171.336-1.009 1.049-2.215 1.464-2.685.672-.751 1.416-1.002 1.596-.696.226.4-.822 3.31-1.089 3.968zm7.427 3.553c-.181.094-.353.156-.431.109-.054-.031.078-.156.078-.156s.932-1.002 1.299-1.456c.211-.266.461-.579.728-.931v.102c.001 1.197-1.158 2.003-1.674 2.332zm5.728-1.307c-.133-.095-.109-.407.336-1.386.173-.384.58-1.024 1.276-1.644.078.251.133.494.125.721-.008 1.51-1.088 2.074-1.737 2.309z"></path>
        <g id="vue_1_">
          <path fill="#41B883" d="M177.17-88.916l-3.713-6.429-3.712 6.429h-12.361l16.073-27.84 16.074 27.84H177.17z" transform="matrix(1.3333 0 0 -1.3333 -76.311 313.34) translate(178.06 235.01)"></path>
          <path fill="#34495E" d="M177.17-88.916l-3.713-6.429-3.712 6.429h-5.931l9.643-16.703 9.645 16.703h-5.932z" transform="matrix(1.3333 0 0 -1.3333 -76.311 313.34) translate(178.06 235.01)"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="javascript_1_">
          <path fill="#F7DF1E" d="M228.879 45.192H272.05899999999997V88.372H228.879z"></path>
          <path d="M257.885 78.927c.869 1.42 2.001 2.464 4.003 2.464 1.681 0 2.755-.841 2.755-2.001 0-1.392-1.104-1.884-2.954-2.694l-1.014-.436c-2.929-1.247-4.873-2.81-4.873-6.113 0-3.043 2.317-5.36 5.942-5.36 2.579 0 4.434.897 5.771 3.249l-3.16 2.029c-.695-1.248-1.446-1.739-2.61-1.739-1.188 0-1.942.754-1.942 1.739 0 1.218.754 1.71 2.495 2.464l1.014.435c3.448 1.478 5.395 2.985 5.395 6.374 0 3.653-2.87 5.654-6.724 5.654-3.769 0-6.203-1.795-7.395-4.149l3.297-1.916zm-14.334.351c.638 1.131 1.218 2.087 2.611 2.087 1.333 0 2.174-.522 2.174-2.55V65.019h4.058v13.852c0 4.201-2.463 6.114-6.059 6.114-3.249 0-5.13-1.681-6.087-3.707l3.303-2z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="node_1_">
          <g fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd">
            <path fill="#333" d="M310.975 414.782a.94.94 0 00-.471-.819l-7.807-4.492a.906.906 0 00-.429-.123h-.082a.926.926 0 00-.43.123l-7.807 4.492a.947.947 0 00-.471.819l.017 12.096c0 .168.088.325.235.407a.454.454 0 00.469 0l4.639-2.656a.949.949 0 00.472-.818v-5.65a.94.94 0 01.47-.816l1.977-1.138a.938.938 0 01.941 0l1.975 1.138a.938.938 0 01.472.816v5.65c0 .336.181.646.473.818l4.638 2.656a.47.47 0 00.706-.407l.013-12.096zM348.532 398.154a.473.473 0 00-.701.412v11.979a.331.331 0 01-.496.286l-1.954-1.127a.943.943 0 00-.942.001l-7.809 4.506a.944.944 0 00-.471.816v9.015c0 .337.18.647.471.816l7.808 4.51a.94.94 0 00.943 0l7.81-4.51a.942.942 0 00.472-.816V401.57a.94.94 0 00-.484-.822l-4.647-2.594zm-.724 22.926a.238.238 0 01-.118.204l-2.682 1.545a.233.233 0 01-.234 0l-2.682-1.545a.236.236 0 01-.118-.204v-3.096c0-.084.045-.162.118-.204l2.681-1.548a.23.23 0 01.235 0l2.682 1.548c.072.042.118.12.118.204v3.096zM374.532 417.904a.944.944 0 00.469-.816v-2.184a.942.942 0 00-.469-.816l-7.759-4.504a.942.942 0 00-.944-.002l-7.807 4.506a.946.946 0 00-.471.817v9.012c0 .339.182.651.478.819l7.756 4.42a.941.941 0 00.925.006l4.691-2.608a.472.472 0 00.007-.82l-7.856-4.509a.472.472 0 01-.236-.409v-2.825c0-.168.089-.323.235-.407l2.444-1.409a.474.474 0 01.472 0l2.445 1.409a.47.47 0 01.237.407v2.223a.47.47 0 00.708.408l4.675-2.718z"></path>
            <path fill="#699F63" d="M366.187 417.481a.183.183 0 01.181 0l1.499.864a.18.18 0 01.09.157v1.729a.181.181 0 01-.09.157l-1.499.864a.178.178 0 01-.181 0l-1.497-.864a.18.18 0 01-.091-.157v-1.729c0-.065.034-.125.091-.157l1.497-.864z"></path>
          </g>
          <defs>
            <path id="SVGID_1_" d="M323.099 409.63l-7.765 4.479a.942.942 0 00-.468.813v8.969a.94.94 0 00.468.813l7.765 4.484c.29.168.647.168.938 0l7.763-4.484a.94.94 0 00.468-.813v-8.969a.94.94 0 00-.47-.813l-7.761-4.479a.935.935 0 00-.938 0"></path>
          </defs>
          <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
            <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"></use>
          </clipPath>
          <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" x1="-47.339" x2="-47.155" y1="553.322" y2="553.322" gradientTransform="scale(-86.4802 86.4802) rotate(63.886 414.342 313.982)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.329" stop-color="#418B3D"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.635" stop-color="#419637"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.932" stop-color="#3FA92D"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#3FAE2A"></stop>
          </linearGradient>
          <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" d="M340.113 413.35L328.896 436.233 307.019 425.51 318.237 402.625z" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)"></path>
          <defs>
            <path id="SVGID_4_" d="M315.058 424.461c.074.097.167.18.276.242l6.66 3.847 1.109.638a.938.938 0 00.726.088l8.187-14.992a.982.982 0 00-.218-.174l-5.084-2.934-2.687-1.546a.885.885 0 00-.243-.098l-8.726 14.929z"></path>
          </defs>
          <clipPath id="SVGID_5_">
            <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_4_"></use>
          </clipPath>
          <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" x1="-48.999" x2="-48.815" y1="549.275" y2="549.275" gradientTransform="scale(132.7982 -132.7982) rotate(36.459 815.39 351.127)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.138" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.403" stop-color="#54A044"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.714" stop-color="#66B848"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.908" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
          </linearGradient>
          <path fill="url(#SVGID_6_)" d="M305.6 416.521L326.028 401.428 341.476 422.335 321.046 437.43z" clip-path="url(#SVGID_5_)"></path>
          <g>
            <defs>
              <path id="SVGID_7_" d="M323.099 409.63l-7.765 4.479a.942.942 0 00-.468.813v8.969a.94.94 0 00.468.813l7.765 4.484c.29.168.647.168.938 0l7.763-4.484a.94.94 0 00.468-.813v-8.969a.94.94 0 00-.47-.813l-7.761-4.479a.935.935 0 00-.938 0"></path>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_8_">
              <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_7_"></use>
            </clipPath>
            <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_8_)">
              <defs>
                <path id="SVGID_9_" d="M322.84 407.982L322.733 408.043 322.876 408.043z"></path>
              </defs>
              <clipPath id="SVGID_10_">
                <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_9_"></use>
              </clipPath>
              <linearGradient id="SVGID_11_" x1="-47.248" x2="-47.061" y1="548.545" y2="548.545" gradientTransform="matrix(97.417 0 0 -97.417 4917.313 53845.625)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.092" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.286" stop-color="#66B848"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.597" stop-color="#54A044"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.862" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
              </linearGradient>
              <path fill="url(#SVGID_11_)" d="M322.733 407.982H322.876V408.043H322.733z" clip-path="url(#SVGID_10_)"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g>
            <defs>
              <path id="SVGID_12_" d="M323.473 409.509a.94.94 0 00-.374.121l-7.743 4.468 8.348 15.205a.936.936 0 00.334-.115l7.763-4.484a.943.943 0 00.453-.641l-8.511-14.539a1.01 1.01 0 00-.27-.015"></path>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_13_">
              <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_12_"></use>
            </clipPath>
            <linearGradient id="SVGID_14_" x1="-47.247" x2="-47.063" y1="549.063" y2="549.063" gradientTransform="matrix(97.417 0 0 -97.417 4917.313 53907.438)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
              <stop offset="0" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
              <stop offset="0.092" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
              <stop offset="0.286" stop-color="#66B848"></stop>
              <stop offset="0.597" stop-color="#54A044"></stop>
              <stop offset="0.862" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
              <stop offset="1" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <path fill="url(#SVGID_14_)" d="M315.355 409.506H332.252V429.303H315.355z" clip-path="url(#SVGID_13_)"></path>
          </g>
          <g>
            <defs>
              <path id="SVGID_15_" d="M323.099 409.63l-7.765 4.479a.942.942 0 00-.468.813v8.969a.94.94 0 00.468.813l7.765 4.484c.29.168.647.168.938 0l7.763-4.484a.94.94 0 00.468-.813v-8.969a.94.94 0 00-.47-.813l-7.761-4.479a.935.935 0 00-.938 0"></path>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_16_">
              <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_15_"></use>
            </clipPath>
            <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_16_)">
              <defs>
                <path id="SVGID_17_" d="M332.543 424.559L332.492 424.471 332.492 424.589z"></path>
              </defs>
              <clipPath id="SVGID_18_">
                <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_17_"></use>
              </clipPath>
              <linearGradient id="SVGID_19_" x1="-47.23" x2="-47.063" y1="549.295" y2="549.295" gradientTransform="matrix(97.417 0 0 -97.417 4917.313 53935.25)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.092" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.286" stop-color="#66B848"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.597" stop-color="#54A044"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.862" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
              </linearGradient>
              <path fill="url(#SVGID_19_)" d="M332.492 424.471H332.543V424.589H332.492z" clip-path="url(#SVGID_18_)"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g>
            <defs>
              <path id="SVGID_20_" d="M323.099 409.63l-7.765 4.479a.942.942 0 00-.468.813v8.969a.94.94 0 00.468.813l7.765 4.484c.29.168.647.168.938 0l7.763-4.484a.94.94 0 00.468-.813v-8.969a.94.94 0 00-.47-.813l-7.761-4.479a.935.935 0 00-.938 0"></path>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_21_">
              <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_20_"></use>
            </clipPath>
            <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_21_)">
              <defs>
                <path id="SVGID_22_" d="M331.818 424.703l-7.772 4.484a.903.903 0 01-.343.117l.155.281 8.634-4.997v-.118l-.214-.365a.975.975 0 01-.46.598"></path>
              </defs>
              <clipPath id="SVGID_23_">
                <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_22_"></use>
              </clipPath>
              <linearGradient id="SVGID_24_" x1="-47.248" x2="-47.063" y1="549.401" y2="549.401" gradientTransform="matrix(97.417 0 0 -97.417 4917.313 53947.875)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.092" stop-color="#6CC04A"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.286" stop-color="#66B848"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.597" stop-color="#54A044"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.862" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
              </linearGradient>
              <path fill="url(#SVGID_24_)" d="M323.703 424.105H332.49199999999996V429.58500000000004H323.703z" clip-path="url(#SVGID_23_)"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g>
            <defs>
              <path id="SVGID_25_" d="M323.099 409.63l-7.765 4.479a.942.942 0 00-.468.813v8.969a.94.94 0 00.468.813l7.765 4.484c.29.168.647.168.938 0l7.763-4.484a.94.94 0 00.468-.813v-8.969a.94.94 0 00-.47-.813l-7.761-4.479a.935.935 0 00-.938 0"></path>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_26_">
              <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_25_"></use>
            </clipPath>
            <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_26_)">
              <defs>
                <path id="SVGID_27_" d="M331.818 424.703l-7.772 4.484a.903.903 0 01-.343.117l.155.281 8.634-4.997v-.118l-.214-.365a.975.975 0 01-.46.598"></path>
              </defs>
              <clipPath id="SVGID_28_">
                <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_27_"></use>
              </clipPath>
              <linearGradient id="SVGID_29_" x1="-47.816" x2="-47.632" y1="552.229" y2="552.229" gradientTransform="scale(-136.498 136.498) rotate(63.886 415.297 314.003)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#41873F"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.329" stop-color="#418B3D"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.635" stop-color="#419637"></stop>
                <stop offset="0.932" stop-color="#3FA92D"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#3FAE2A"></stop>
              </linearGradient>
              <path fill="url(#SVGID_29_)" d="M334.656 425.168L330.788 433.06 321.537 428.524 325.405 420.633z" clip-path="url(#SVGID_28_)"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="gridsome_1_">
          <linearGradient id="SVGID_30_" x1="417.623" x2="417.623" y1="189.817" y2="167.523" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 8.4 477.04)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#00583E"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00835C"></stop>
          </linearGradient>
          <path fill="url(#SVGID_30_)" d="M441.284 287.41c1.816-.088 3.425 1.321 3.581 3.139.68 8.795-7.369 18.647-18.712 18.963-9.559.236-19.012-7.416-19.012-18.987 0-1.823 1.507-3.302 3.325-3.302s3.292 1.479 3.292 3.302c0 7.61 6.12 12.536 12.232 12.386 7.524-.209 12.417-6.725 12.162-12.045a3.3 3.3 0 013.132-3.456z"></path>
          <path fill="#00A672" d="M433.059 290.78c0-1.867 1.523-3.38 3.401-3.38h4.957c1.879 0 3.448 1.513 3.448 3.38s-1.569 3.38-3.448 3.38h-4.957c-1.878 0-3.401-1.513-3.401-3.38zM422.658 290.785c0-1.869 1.514-3.385 3.378-3.385s3.378 1.516 3.378 3.385-1.514 3.385-3.378 3.385-3.378-1.516-3.378-3.385zM429.32 274.969a3.3 3.3 0 01-3.153 3.436c-7.844.326-12.632 6.491-12.398 12.345.072 1.821-1.313 3.358-3.13 3.431-1.816.072-3.414-1.398-3.487-3.22-.379-9.538 7.563-18.968 18.742-19.153a3.293 3.293 0 013.426 3.161z"></path>
        </g>
      </g>
        
          <path fill="#B64401" d="M297.298 205.815c-.1.08-.271.16-.49.23-.79.26-2.3.45-4.38.59-.49.03-1.02.06-1.58.08-.08.01-.16.01-.24.01-.409.02-.83.04-1.27.05-.33.02-.68.03-1.04.04-.59.02-1.21.03-1.85.04-18.37.36-55.01-1.13-72.331-1.91-.32-.01-.63-.03-.93-.04-.91-.04-1.76-.08-2.54-.11-.42-.02-.81-.04-1.19-.06-3.06-.14-4.83-.23-4.83-.23-.51-.55-1.06-1.25-1.62-2.06-3.41-4.84-7.35-13.41-5.08-15.18 2.65-2.07 6.62-.51 6.7-1.72.09-1.21-6.25-10.52-3.69-13.45 2.57-2.93 2.57-.34 3.69-1.38.65-.6-1.17-4.97-1.56-9.38-.06-.6-.08-1.2-.08-1.79.04-2.56.75-4.95 2.93-6.42 1.51-1.02 2.4-1.83 2.92-2.49 1.71-2.15-.36-2.82 2.49-4.4 3.73-2.07 8.56 1.03 8.56 1.03s6.72-12.58 10.17-13.1c3.45-.52 3.1 4.65 6.04 3.96 2.93-.69 7.24-6.72 10.86-7.93 5.229-1.74-1.48 5.52 1.03 5.52 2.52 0 8.11-6.9 16.21-8.1 2.76 2.41-1.21 6.38 5.17 7.41 6.38 1.04 3.449 6.55 7.59 8.45 4.14 1.9 3.62.52 7.76 1.9 4.13 1.37 2.63 2.75 3.81 7.24 1.19 4.48.15 5.34 4.551 7.76 4.399 2.41 9.01 4.31 6.699 9.65-2.3 5.35-2.689 9.14 0 8.1 2.7-1.03 3.211-1.2 2.521 1.9-.69 3.1-5.86 10.35-1.55 10.35 4.31 0 .47 12.36-3.45 15.44z"></path>
          <path fill="#B64401" d="M294.058 203.565l-.03.96c-.05 1.04-.75 1.79-1.6 2.11-.51.19-1.08.23-1.58.08-.03 0-.06-.01-.09-.02-.05.02-.1.03-.15.03-.409.12-.85.13-1.27.05a2.28 2.28 0 01-1.021-.44c-.31-.24-.56-.56-.699-.96a2.403 2.403 0 01-.13-.92c.17-3.81-.16-7.44-1.08-11.16-.391-1.55.64-2.61 1.83-2.85.039-.02.09-.02.13-.03-.19-.82-.41-1.63-.66-2.43 0-.01 0-.01-.01-.02a29.446 29.446 0 00-1.506-3.898c-.075-.15-.146-.303-.225-.452-.08-.15-.16-.3-.24-.44-.01-.02-.01-.03-.02-.05-.05-.11-.12-.23-.19-.34a4.76 4.76 0 00-.39-.65 17.92 17.92 0 00-1.771-2.43c-.05-.06-.1-.13-.159-.19-3.311-3.78-7.9-6.16-12.74-8.09-11.61-4.61-25.12-4.27-37.28-1.42.35 1.69-.34 3.52-2.5 4-6.18 2.06-10.91 5.33-16.01 8.94h-.01c-.67.47-1.34.95-2.03 1.43 0 2.08-.17 4.22-.58 6.45-.03.2-.08.4-.14.59.78 1.91 1.47 3.98 1.85 6.04.03.03.05.06.08.09.33.38.63.84.85 1.39.76 1.91.36 3.59-.63 4.96v.01c-.25.36-.54.69-.87 1-.02.03-.05.05-.08.08-.34.62-.78 1.17-1.28 1.63-.65.61-1.41 1.08-2.23 1.41-.23.08-.47.16-.71.22-.14.05-.27.08-.41.11-1.72.38-3.6.17-5.28-.74-.96-.52-1.93-1.27-2.86-2.19.47-.97 1.08-1.79 1.8-2.37.29-.24.58-.44.87-.61-3.41-4.84-7.35-13.41-5.08-15.18 2.65-2.07 6.62-.51 6.7-1.72.09-1.21-6.25-10.52-3.69-13.45 2.57-2.93 2.57-.34 3.69-1.38.65-.6-1.17-4.97-1.56-9.38.02-.01.05-.01.07-.02-.08-.59-.14-1.19-.15-1.77.04-2.56.75-4.95 2.93-6.42 1.51-1.02 2.4-1.83 2.92-2.49.38.1.69.49.55.92-1.19 3.52-2.59 6.21-1.21 9.94.83-.95 1.72-1.83 2.67-2.7 1.99-1.82 4.85.78 3.48 2.79.73.03 1.45.14 2.16.33 1.53-3.49 3.27-6.8 7.12-8.46 1.44-.62 3.4.41 2.85 2.2-.14.44-.3.95-.46 1.5.36-.62.65-1.11.82-1.36 1.24-1.85 3.95-2.35 5.87-1.53 2.03-1.95 4.1-3.86 6.22-5.68 3.52-3.02 6.86-5.07 11.57-4.38 2.959.43 3.11 4.84.799 6.15-.76.48-1.5 1-2.22 1.52-.79.63-1.53 1.32-2.23 2.09l-.02.03c-.18.27-1.7 2.15-2.67 3.24.06.08.14.14.19.22 2.75-.48 5.59-1.87 7.81-2.77 3.48-1.41 6.72-2.4 10.51-2.45 2.63-.03 4.04 2.44 3.79 4.61 3.54.13 7.08.15 10.641.01 1.479-.06 2.18 1.37 2 2.62-.13.82-.32 1.53-.59 2.19.96-.12 1.93-.2 2.899-.23 1.15-.02 1.271 1.59.26 1.92-1.989.67-4.029 1.15-6.05 1.73-1.17.34-2.37-1.02-1.75-2.1-1.479.51-2.95.77-4.45.85 2.24.68 4.41 1.51 6.5 2.54 13.562 6.69 18.532 23.101 18.162 37.19z" opacity="0.31"></path>
          <path fill="#FFB890" d="M212.388 227.096c-.2 0-.39-.01-.58-.03-12.29-.68-14.81-14.96-11.47-21.64.47-.97 1.08-1.79 1.8-2.37.29-.24.58-.44.87-.61 2.62-1.58 4.84-.5 6.42.98.46.44.87.91 1.22 1.37.58.75.99 1.45 1.18 1.82.1.17.15.27.15.27l.41 20.21z"></path>
          <path fill="#F29B62" d="M206.683 214.295c.034-.262.084-.522.146-.78.396-1.648 1.357-3.282 2.297-4.683.225-.334-.208-.752-.542-.551-3.048 1.836-5.708 5.773-4.432 9.46.978 2.826 5.614 4.692 7.109 1.282 1.178-2.684-1.648-6.546-4.578-4.728z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFB890" d="M285.788 228.456c-.03.01-.05.01-.08.01a8.7 8.7 0 01-.521.02l.011-.69.399-19.51s.3-.62.851-1.43c.47-.69 1.119-1.52 1.93-2.23 1.74-1.54 4.2-2.49 7.06-.17.521.42.98.96 1.37 1.59 3.95 6.26 1.759 21.7-11.02 22.41z"></path>
          <path fill="#F29B62" d="M290.889 215.694a7.753 7.753 0 00-.146-.78c-.396-1.648-1.357-3.282-2.298-4.683-.225-.334.209-.752.542-.552 3.048 1.836 5.709 5.773 4.432 9.461-.978 2.826-5.614 4.692-7.109 1.281-1.178-2.683 1.648-6.545 4.579-4.727z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFC9AE" d="M288.215 194.186c0 3.65-.039 7.13-.149 10.44-.021.74-.05 1.47-.08 2.19-.12 3.14-.31 6.12-.58 8.95-.19 1.98-.41 3.89-.69 5.72-.35 2.43-.779 4.73-1.31 6.9 0 .02 0 .05-.01.08-1.53 6.29-3.83 11.44-7.22 15.44-5.931 7.01-15.2 10.52-29.57 10.52-14.58 0-23.92-3.61-29.84-10.84-2.82-3.44-4.86-7.71-6.33-12.79-.34-1.2-.66-2.44-.94-3.73-.49-2.22-.89-4.57-1.21-7.05-.24-1.77-.43-3.62-.59-5.53-.26-3.07-.44-6.32-.55-9.75-.01-.43-.03-.87-.03-1.31-.09-2.95-.12-6.03-.12-9.24-.001-36.721 79.219-36.721 79.219 0z"></path>
        </g>
       
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS animation in Firefox not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143893/css-animation-in-firefox-not-work)

Comment: Kindly tell if my answer works for you or not?

Comment: No, It doesn't work. You can check here.

https://codepen.io/lakers19/pen/QWypvLx

Comment: And also, @keyframe animations are directly supported by firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in Firefox.  It seems it might be getting confused because you are using the same animation for the `#techs` group and its children.

The fix is to change the parent group animation to use an absolute `transform-origin`.  I've used the coordinates of the centre of the background circle.  It also has the advantage of making the rotation animation smoother.

```
#techs {
     animation: rotate 10s infinite linear;
     transform-origin: 252px 247px;
}
 #techs > * {
     animation: inherit;
     animation-direction: reverse;
     transform-origin: center;
     transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

Comment: I suspect it's [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1612347)

Answer (score -1):

use `-moz-` for animations as well as animation properties also-

```
@-moz-keyframes animation-name {
  -moz-transform: ;
}
```

Link to a related question is [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143893/css-animation-in-firefox-not-work). So check it out!
Try updating your Firefox browser, if any update is available!

Comment: No, Still doesn't work. You can check here https://codepen.io/lakers19/pen/QWypvLx

Comment: And also, @keyframe animations are directly supported by firefox.

Comment: -moz- is used for earlier versions of FF, nowadays it supports without that also